# Flutter videoplayer end to end

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I'm trying to make a flutter videoplayer with an encrypted video, how can I do to decrypt the file with an algorithm made by me?
is there a way to have access to the buffer before giving it to the videoplayer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package, it accepts `File` as inputs.

So instead of giving the encrypted video from the web as the source for the controller:

```
_videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl)
```

What you can do instead is get your video from the web yourself, and decrypt it (I assume that at the end of this process you'd have a `Uint8List`). Then, convert it into a `File` and give it to the video player as the source:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

...

final video = fetchVideo(videoUrl);
final Uint8List decryptedVideoBytes = decryptVideo(video);
final File videoFile = File.fromRawPath(Uint8List uint8List);
_videoController = VideoPlayerController.file(videoFile);
```

Comment: I thought about it, but the problem is that the size of the files is 20/30 GiB, with a loading time that is too high.

Comment: I see, that's an interesting use case. Then, I think you might need to go down to the platform level for this. video_player uses the following interface which does not have any methods to access any kind of buffer: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/video_player/video_player_platform_interface/lib/video_player_platform_interface.dart